# how to make c++11 auto smarter?

Tags: c++, c++11

I am now beginning to use auto keyword in c++ 11. One thing I found it not so smart is illustrated in the following code:

```
unsigned int a = 7;
unsigned int b = 23;
auto c = a - b;
std::cout << c << std::endl;
```

As you can see, the type of `c` variable is unsigned int. But my intention is the difference of two unsigned int should be int. So I expect variable `c` is equal to -16.  How could I use auto more wisely so that it can infer the type of `c` variable to int? Thanks.

Comment: "As you can see, I expect the type of `c` variable should be `int`" why did you expect that?

Comment: `7u - 23u` is a valid unsigned calculation. Why do you expect it to change?

Comment: `auto` is very smart. Integral promotion rules just don't apply here (i.e there is no need for promotion).

Comment: @Bob__ Thanks God, you cannot overload for *int*s.

Comment: It is a C++ rule that what you do with a result does not change how that result is computed. The rules are complex enough already! If they had to take into account what you do with a result, they'd be unusuably complex. That you put `auto c` on the left of the `=` has no effect on how the operation on the right of the `=` is done, and it's going to underflow.

Comment: But c _is_ equal to -16 ! (Modulo UINT_MAX).

Comment: neither `int` or `unsigned int` can store the full range of the result of the subtraction between 2 `unsigned int`s. You should use a wider type instead

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc - [Unsigned arithmetic is well defined](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.fundamental#4)

Comment: @StoryTeller Yes of course I know. But sometimes you don't need the wraparound behavior but need to store the full result from `0 - UINT_MAX` to `UINT_MAX - 0`. In that case neither int or unsigned int will have

Comment: If you want the type of `c` to be `int` write it as `int`.

Comment: Every novice program should learn that compiler does what you order it to do, not what you want it to do.

Answer (score 6):

Both `a` and `b` have a type of *unsigned int*. Consequently, the type of expression `a - b` is deduced as *unsigned int* and `c` has a type of *unsigned int*. So *auto* here works as it is supposed to do.

If you want to change a type from *unsigned int* to *int* you might use *static_cast*:

```
auto c = static_cast<int>(a - b);
```

Or explicitly specify the type for `c`:

```
int c = a - b;
```

Comment: `int c = a - b;` Too safe and simple! We must use as many C++1x features as possible for the sake of posing!

Comment: @Lundin Like `decltype(auto) c = [](auto a, auto b) { return a - b; } (a, b);`?

Comment: Yeah exactly! You win a date with Bjarne Stroustrup.

Answer (score 1):

You misunderstand what `unsigned int` type is.

`unsigned int` is a mod-`2^k` for some `k` (usually 32) integer.  Subtracting two such mod-`2^k` integers is well defined, and is not a signed integer.

If you want a type that models a bounded set of integers from `-2^k` to `2^k-1` (with k usually equal to 31), use `int` instead of `unsigned int`.  If you want them to be positive, simply make them positive.

Despite its name, `unsigned int` is not an `int` that has no sign and is thus positive.  Instead, it is a very specific integral type that happens to have no notion of sign.

If you don't need mod-`2^k` math for some unknown implementation defined `k`, and are not desparate for every single bit of of magnitude to be packed into a value, don't use `unsigned int`.

What you appear to want is something like

```
positive<int> a = 7;
positive<int> b = 23;
auto c = a-b; // c is of type `int`, because the difference of two positive values may be negative
```

With a few syntax changes and a lot of work that might be possible, but it isn't what `unsigned` means.

Answer (score 1):

So just because *you* don't know how basic expressions work, the C++11 auto keyword is dumb? How does that even make any sense to you?

In the expression `auto c = a - b;`, the `auto c =` has nothing whatsoever to do with the type used in the sub-expression `a - b`.

Ever since the very first C language draft, **the type used by an expression is determined by the operands of that expression**. This is true for everything from pre-standard K&R C to C++17.

Now what you need to do if you want negative numbers is, not too surprisingly, to use negative types. Change the operands to (signed) `int` or cast them to that type before invoking the `-` operator.

Declaring the result as a signed type without changing the type of the operands of `-` is not a good idea, because then you force a conversion from unsigned to signed, which isn't necessarily well-defined behavior.

---

Now, if the operands have different types, or are of small integer types, they will get implicitly promoted as per *the usual arithmetic conversions*. That does not apply in this specific case, since both operands are of the same type and not of a small integer type.

But... *this* is why the `auto` keyword is dumb and dangerous. Consider:

```
unsigned short a = 7;
unsigned short b = 23;
auto c = a - b;
```

Since both operands were unsigned, the programmer intended to use unsigned arithmetic. But here both operands are implicitly promoted to `int`, with an unintended change of signedness. The `auto` keyword pretends that nothing happened, whereas `unsigned int c = a - b;` would increase the chance of compiler diagnostic messages, or at least increase the chance of warnings from external static analysis tools. And it will also accidentally smoother out what could have otherwise been a change-of-signedness bug.

In addition, with `auto` we would end up with the wrong, unintended type for the declared variable.